# Azure-cli Remove all VM and disks and everything under resource group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I am wondering is there a way to remove all resources under a particular resource group?

I have tried `Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name XXX -Force` but it fails and I get resources are locked and the resource group cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this first to remove the resource locks, then you can run your  `Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup` command.  Also, I have to mention that AzureRM PowerShell modules will be retired on 29 February 2024 and you should update to the  **Az PowerShell** modules.

```
Get-AzureRmResourceLock | where ResourceGroupName -eq XXX | Remove-AzureRmResourceLock -Force
```